# Python program freeze when trying to open .jar file

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, jar, freeze

so i tried multiple methods to make my python code not freeze aster opening a jar file but i can't do anything, the program wont stop being frozen until the jar file is closed.

i tried multiple things to make it work but none managed to so far(Popen,os.sys,PyQt5 though i didn't manage to make it work)

Btw, i am using it to open the .jar of some Shimeji

here is the code, thank you in advance for your help:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import shutil
import os
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark") # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

def UpdateShimeji(FolderName, path):
    ico_file = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.ico')][0]
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./Shimeji/" + ico_file))
    panel = tkinter.Label(ShimejiFrame, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

def FileExplorer():
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_name = folder_path[folder_path.rfind('/'):]
    shutil.copytree(folder_path,'./Shimeji/' + folder_name)
    jar_file = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.jar')][0]
#os.system('cd "./Shimeji/' + folder_name + '" & ' + jar_file)
#UpdateShimeji(folder_name, folder_path)

app = customtkinter.CTk() # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
app.geometry("500x440")
app.minsize(width=500, height=440)
app.maxsize(width=500, height=440)
app.title("Shimeji Tool")
ico = Image.open('ico.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ico)
app.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)
ShimejiFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app)

bar = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, fg_color='#404040',width=510,height=22,corner_radius=0)
bar.grid(row=0,column=0)
fileButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, command=FileExplorer,     fg_color='#292929',hover_color='#242424', text="File",corner_radius=0.2, width=50,height=0.1)
fileButton.place(x=0,y=0)

app.mainloop()
```

i tried os.sys(), subprocess, PyQt5(i did not manage to make it work in any way), and other ways i don't remember

Comment: On Windows you can use `os.startfile`.

Comment: doesn't work with shimeji jars, idk why

Comment: from what i found. anything that specifies what the file is going to use to open is going to fail

Comment: You'll need to run this jar file in a separate process. You might want to research python's multiprocessing module.

Comment: What do you mean by *opening a jar file*? Read its contents? Execute it?

Comment: execute, but even with the multiprocessing it doesn't seem to work. it opens a second window and only after all the windows have been closed it execute the jar file

Comment: You need Java executable to execute the JAR file.

Comment: that's what i tried to do, but it just opens the jar without any kind of UI or process, it just opens it in the task manager but it's like it doesn't exist

Comment: You might be using the multiprocessing module wrong. There’s a very common mistake that we see a lot. Please show what you’ve tried.

Comment: okay here it is: https://pastebin.com/hnhfUY9D

Comment: Normally `java -jar some.jar` is used to execute a JAR file.

Comment: yeah i tried that but it doesn't work either

Comment: Did you try the command in a console/terminal directly? Does it work?

Comment: gave me this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. but when i double click it, it works so the jar ain't broken but is at the same time

Comment: If your platform is Windows, try `os.system("cd ./shimeji/some_path && start /b java -jar shimeji-ee.jar")`.

Comment: i think i found the thing, in the manifest there is the Main-Class variable, it points to the main class. the problem is that even though the folders are named correctly it doesn't detect the class